# ASP.NET Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have an ASP.NET website set up using Windows authentication. Each time I open IE and try to access the webpage I get a windows authentication screen.  Once I have logged in I can see the website fine.  My problem is that every time I open a new IE browser I have to re-enter my username and password.  I have heard about thew double hop issue, is this what it could be. If so how many ip fix this.

Any ideas how i can stop this box showing up each time? I have ticked the "remember my username/password" tick box but still no joy.

I am using Windows Server 2003, IIS 6.0 and .NET 4.0.

Thanks

JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using:

> Internet Explorer > Tools > Options >
>   Security > Custom Level (Internet) >
>   Scroll down and go to User
>   Authenotication - Logon and select
>   Automatic Login using current username
>   and password.

This will take the curent NT username and password, the user has logged in with.

I dont think this cant be done progamatically using your server code from your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got Integrated Authentication enabled in Internet Explorer?
[image]
<sub>(source: [philippursglove.com](http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/ieintegratedauthentication.png))</sub>

If you're logged onto the client machine as a domain user, that setting allows IE to pass your credentials through to ASP.NET.