# Windows Authentication mode - how to make it not ask for credentials?

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

I have configured my ASP.NET website to use windows auth (and disabled annon auth), and setup some authorization rules. The website is deployed on the Intranet and all users have a windows identity.

When a user navigates to the website, the typical "Windows Security" window pops up, asking the user for his identity. I want to disable this, since the user is already logged in with a domain account. The browser should submit the current identity and IIS can use this to auth.

Any ideas?

Note: I am using IE and the Enable Integrated Windows Authentication is checked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068979/asp-net-windows-authentication

Answer (score 1):

In which browser is this happening? Internet Explorer has an option that explicitly defines whether the browser tries to authenticate users automatically.

You can find it in Tools - Internet Options - Advanced - Enable Integrated Windows Authentication.

Comment: Yes, I am using IE 9 and that option is ON (I believe it's on by default)

Answer (score 1):

Where I've seen this symptom happening before, I've had to add the URL the website is on explicitly into the `Local Intranet` zone in IE.

Comment: I have this same issue on ie 6... which doesn't even seem to have the concept of a local intranet zone